# GraphQL : `_contained_in` syntax for search matching key and value pair from jsob field

Tags: graphql, jsonb, array-contains

**Unable to create Query for `_contained_in` using Hasura Graphql**

#### `_contains` Query

```
query MyQuery($data_rule_list: jsonb) {
  mbr_pgm(where: {nom_org_id: {_eq: "XXX"}, data_rule_list: {_contains: $data_rule_list}}) {
    data_rule_list
    key_wrd_txt
    updt_ver_nbr
  }
}
```

#### Variable :

```
{
  "data_rule_list": {
    "offerNumber": "0196819"
  }
}
```

Facing Issue to Create `_contained_in` query

#### If Query for `_contained_in` is :

```
query MyQuery($data_rule_list: jsonb) {
  mbr_pgm(where: {nom_org_id: {_eq: "XXX"}, data_rule_list: {_contained_in: $data_rule_list}}) {
    data_rule_list
    key_wrd_txt
    updt_ver_nbr
  }
}
```

#### What should be the Variables ?

I Tried. Not Working

```
{
  "data_rule_list": {
    "value": [
      {
        "offerNumber": "0196819"
      },
      {
        "offerNumber": "0196820"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please give more details about how it is "not working". Are you getting an error message? Does it just not return the desired results?

Comment: Its return blank result